# Selenium not using webdriver.firefox.profile when using JSON Wire Protocol

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, nightwatch.js

I launched the profile manager and created a new profile named foo. I selected to use this profile by default when launching firefox, then launched firefox and closed it.

I start selenium using the argument `-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=foo`. I see in the server's output that this has been set as the default profile.

When starting a new session via NightwatchJS (JSON Wire Protocol), however, an anonymous profile is created for the session rather than using the pre-created profile. I also tried passing in the `firefox_profile` desired capability, but this did not seem to make a difference.

Is this a known issue, and is there some sort of workaround?

- Selenium Version: 2.45.0
- Firefox Versions tested: 28, 35, 38
- Nightwatch Version: 0.6.9 (I do not believe this is related to Nightwatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the target profile in your **nighwatch.json** configuration file :

## Solution 1

in the global selenium config:

http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#selenium-settings

```
"selenium" : {
  ...
  "cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "foo"
  }
},
```

## Solution 2

in the browser config:

Follow the 3rd part of this doc: https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/wiki/Enable-Firebug-in-Firefox-for-Nightwatch-tests

> 3) Configure Nightwatch to use the new profile
>
> Open your nightwatch.json file and in your test_settings add a property called > firefox_profile under the desired environment (e.g. "default"). Set this property to the new firefox profile name you have created in step 1 (e.g. "foo").

```
"test_settings" : {
   "default" : {
     ...
     "firefox_profile" : "foo",
     ...
   }
}
```

Be careful ! it's **not** a "desiredCapability" parameter ;-)